# Number winning streak ID's in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transform, pandas-groupby

I have a Python pandas dataframe with winning streaks for some teams over several time periods and I would like to identfy the streaks chronologically. So, what I have is:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'period': list(range(1,7))+list(range(1,6)),
    'team_id':       ['A']*6 + ['B']*5,
    'win':           [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1],
    'streak_length': [1,2,3,0,1,2,1,0,0,1,2]})
print(data)
```

And what I would like to have is:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'period': list(range(1,7))+list(range(1,6)),
    'team_id':       ['A']*6 + ['B']*5,
    'win':           [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1],
    'streak_length': [1,2,3,0,1,2,1,0,0,1,2],
    'streak_id':     [1,1,1,None,2,2,1,None,None,2,2]})
print(result)
```

I tried to groupby by `team_id` and sum over streak length, but it can be repeated, so I think this would not work. Any help appreciated!

Comment: FYI if you can move this computation back to the same code that already computed `streak_length`, it's going to be easier.

Comment: Note it might result in simpler code to generate zeros instead of `None` for the `win == 0` rows; then just translate 0 to `None` at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create consecutive groups by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), filter only `1` in `win` and use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) in lambda function:

```
m = data['win'].eq(1)
g = data['win'].ne(data['win'].shift()).cumsum()

data['streak_id'] = g[m].groupby(data['team_id']).transform(
    lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1
)

print (data)
    period team_id  win  streak_length  streak_id
0        1       A    1              1        1.0
1        2       A    1              2        1.0
2        3       A    1              3        1.0
3        4       A    0              0        NaN
4        5       A    1              1        2.0
5        6       A    1              2        2.0
6        1       B    1              1        1.0
7        2       B    0              0        NaN
8        3       B    0              0        NaN
9        4       B    1              1        2.0
10       5       B    1              2        2.0
```

Comment: It helps a lot to explain the magic. `g` gives a unique increasing number to all streaks (win or lose). `g[m]` just slices the winning streaks, and preserves their index. Throws away losing streaks; they will end up as `NaN`. Finally group into distinct teams and the `.transform()` with `pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1` throws away the winning-streak numbering, and renumbers winning-streaks consecutively.